# Allow symlinks not working

Tags: magento-1.8, template, configuration

I have a preprod Magento environment and I want to allow symlinks in template setting.

I allowed it via **Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Template** Setting but it's not working. It has worked before.

I have disabled the Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic Googling for the same issue.

Please note that the admin setting to allow symlink has been removed by [SUPEE-9767](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/issues/125).

To re-enable symlinks with Magento 1.9+ with SUPEE-9767, do the following:

Fire up your SQL client and run:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=1 WHERE path='dev/template/allow_symlink';
```

Clean up Magento's cache:

```
n98-magerun.phar cache:dir:flush
```

If your using Vagrant:

```
vagrant halt && vagrant up
```

Now symlinks should work again.

Note: I don't now why this setting is about "templates": it actually seems to drive code too.